# Possible to have a computed property and a method of same name in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a [method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) and [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) of same name, when I try to access these, I am getting following error:

> vue.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: doubleAge is not a function(…)

Following is the simplified code from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/5e473uwt/):

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        age: ''
      };
    },
    computed: {
      doubleAge: function () {
            return 2*this.age
        }
    },
    methods: {
      doubleAge: function () {
         return 'this is from method'
       }
    }   
})
```

I have `doubleAge` as computed property and method both. Is there some other way to call the method in this case, how to make this work?

Comment: An object property can only name one thing. Why don't you give them different names?

Comment: @Barmar I had a case where some places I wanted a variable from computed property and some places I want to get it from backend, may be I can rename it to latestMyVar if it's not possible.

Comment: I tried using vue.js (unminified version), but it didn't give any more descriptive error in this case. Usually the unminified version provides more info than the production version, which you can consider for jsFiddle and development env.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No It's not possible, every property on an object must be uniquely named